# Simultaneous equation difficulty minus

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I've got a simultaneous equation, and have attempted it. Hope you guys could check my answer out.

$\begin{cases}9x-y=-1~......(1)\\-6x+3y=10~......(2)\end{cases}$

$(1)\times3$ :

$27x-3y=3~......(3)$

$(3)-(2)$ :

$21x=-7$

$3x=-1$

Comment: Are you multiplying the first equation by $3$ to get $27x-3y=3$? If so then you've forgotten the negative sign after the equal sign $(-1)$ and therefore it should be $3(9x-y=-1) = 27x-3y=\mathbf {-3}$.

Answer (score 1):

From the second two equations: Yes, $21x = -7 \iff 3x = -1\iff x = -\frac 13$. Now solve for $y$.

In the ***first*** two equations, you should have $27 x = 7 \iff 3x = 1 \iff x = \frac 13$. Now solve for $y$.

ALERT: Note that the two systems you posted are identical, save for the equation $27 - 3y = 3$ in the second "pair". I think you must have multiplying the first equation by $3$, but dropped a "sign". You should have gotten $$27 - 3y = -3,$$ in which case you'll find that $x = \frac 13$ is the solution for $x$..

Comment: :O I dont understand, i thought there's one answer. I was debating whether to do 1/3 since i'd get a ugly number.. but i don't get why you've told me to work out 21x and 27x

Comment: I think you made a typo (lost a sign) when multiplying  the first equation by $3$? That will give one system of equations, one solution $x$: see my expanded post.

Comment: To obtain $y$, plug $x = 1/3$ into either equation. Let's take the first: $9x -y = -1 \iff 9(1/3) - y = -1 \iff y = 4$.

Comment: $\ddot\smile$+1